# Why does git say that my file is outside the repository?

Tags: git, filepath

Hey guys beginner here how do I upload file into github using git.

This is my command:

```
$ git add C:\Users\Dan\Downloads\filecrdownload
fatal: C:UsersDa: 'C:UsersDan' is outside repository
```

What did do wrong? How should I fix this?

Comment: As the error message tells you, the file is outside of the repository. You can't do that with git.

Comment: you can add files only within the repo. Copy that file inside your local repo first and then verify if it;s present by typing git status. if you see your file in that then do git add

Comment: Which command line tool are you using? Are you using Cygwin, or bash on Windows? It looks like you might be referring to files in Windows style (`C:\Users`), but using a shell that expects a forward slash (`/cygdrive/C/Users`), which is why your error message refers to `C:UsersDa`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you already have a repo set up on Github, you'll need to clone it on your computer.

`git clone <url-to-repo>`

The url can be found on the front page for your repo:[image: github repo url]

Clone will create a new directory in your filesystem, and you'll want to move your file into there.

Once the file is inside your git directory, you can simply do:

```
git add filecrdownload
git commit -m "Added filecrdownload"
git push
```

Which stages `filecrdownload`, makes a new commit and pushes that commit. You should now see it on Github.

Answer (score 0):

You can only add the files from a git repo.

You can use `git init` to initialize a git repo in the current location.
Then you can do `git add path_to_your_file`

Answer (score 0):

There is another scenario where you would see that error message: same path with different case (lower/upercase)

```
mkdir "c:\repo"
cmd /K "cd c:\repo\"
git init
echo "content" > file.txt
git add C:\repo\file.txt
```

Note the `add C:\` vs. `c:\`.

This was reported in [git-for-windows/git issue 735](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/735) in 2016, was fixed in [Git for Windows (fork of Git) 2.16 in 2017](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/commit/7df5db8d31e7b384b14e488c76933d46a9e76161), and is now (Feb. 2019) available with Git 2.21.

See [commit d8727b3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d8727b3687c1d249e84be71a581cc1fb0581336a) (18 Jan 2019) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit ff09c9e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ff09c9e5bad8971d25e7e2039836c9d42797e30a), 05 Feb 2019)</sup>

> ### `abspath_part_inside_repo`: respect `core.ignoreCase`
>
> If the file system is case-insensitive, we really must be careful to
> ignore differences in case only.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone gets this on a Unix system on a local, non-bare repo without a remote:

Since the Windows capital/lowercase drive letter thing does not apply, and the path is DEAD SIMILAR with proper full path AND same capitalization, like /home/me/repo/test.txt would NOT add even though everything LOOKED similar:

I took a look in `.git/config` and there was one line

```
precomposeunicode = true
```

Thinking about other replies about character sets etc (who ever works in anything but UTF-8 these days, but still) I changed it on a whim to `FALSE`

And it worked! My commit went through!